# How to solve one of this CodingBat java method?

Tags: arrays, hashmap

Here is my homework:

> We'll say that 2 strings "match" if they are non-empty and their first chars are the same. Loop over and then return the given array of non-empty strings as follows: if a string matches an earlier string in the array, swap the 2 strings in the array. When a position in the array has been swapped, it no longer matches anything. Using a map, this can be solved making just one pass over the array.
>
> ```
> allSwap(["ab", "ac"]) → ["ac", "ab"]
>
> allSwap(["ax", "bx", "cx", "cy", "by", "ay", "aaa", "azz"]) → ["ay", "by", "cy", "cx", "bx", "ax", "azz", "aaa"]
>
> allSwap(["ax", "bx", "ay", "by", "ai", "aj", "bx", "by"]) → ["ay", "by", "ax", "bx", "aj", "ai", "by", "bx"]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the map, store the first letter as the key, and the most recent index of the key as the value. When a letter doesn't exist in the map, add it to the map. When a letter already exists in the map, remove it from the map and swap with that index.

```java
/**
 * Swaps strings in the array that have the same first letter,
 * reading left to right. Once a string has been swapped, 
 * it will not be swapped again. The input array will be mutated.
 * 
 * @param  strings the strings to perform swaps from
 * @return         the strings after swapping
 */
public static String[] allSwap(final String[] strings) {
    // map of first characters, and the index where they were last seen
    final Map<Character, Integer> potentialSwap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int thisIndex = 0; thisIndex < strings.length; thisIndex++) {
        if (strings[thisIndex].isEmpty()) {
            continue; // skip empty strings
        }

        final Character firstChar = strings[thisIndex].charAt(0); // box charAt(0)
        // remove firstChar from the map. If it's not found, returns null
        final Integer potentialIndex = potentialSwap.remove(firstChar);

        if (potentialIndex != null) {
            final int thatIndex = potentialIndex; // unbox potentialIndex
            // swap values at thisIndex and thatIndex
            final String temp = strings[thatIndex];
            strings[thatIndex] = strings[thisIndex];
            strings[thisIndex] = temp;
        } else {
            // save the index for possible swapping later
            potentialSwap.put(firstChar, thisIndex); // box thisIndex
        }
    }

    return strings;
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/0KrLFu)

Comment: This is very helpful, but I wonder what educational purpose might be served when (a) this appears to be a homework question, and (b) the OP appears to have made no prior effort whatsoever. If they hand in this solution, they may have learned nothing.

Comment: @halfer When it comes to answering homework questions, I've always found that showing someone what good code looks like is a huge benefit. I have no way of knowing if they made any attempt before now, but my gamble is that they have, and that they will be a decent human being and actually read the code, and ask questions if they don't understand something.

Comment: @halfer Of course I recognize that homework questions are easily abused, so I make an concerted effort to only answer if the algorithm is reasonably complex, because it means that the asker is at a reasonable level of skill in the language, and has gotten thus far in school based on merit. I'm not here to judge people, just pay my knowledge forward. It's the school's job to test if they have learned something.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the considered response. Your kindness may turn out to be wasted, since my experience is that such questions do not even receive a response, but certainly your karma will be boosted!

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was not my homework question. I didn't write "here is my homework" at the top. I was new to this stackoverflow, I think it was already written there by default.

Comment: @bantybrar "Here is my homework" was added to your question by halfer in order to make it very clear what was wrong with the question. While it may not have been a homework question in reality, it essentially was one, since you were essentially asking other people to write code for you. I went ahead and posted an answer, but you should always show an attempt, and make the question about how your attempt can be made better so that it meets all of the requirements, rather than making it about solving the problem as a whole.

Comment: Yes, I should have posted my attempt also. I could not get more than 90% right on codigbat with my attempt. I struggled with this problem for 2-3 days. It was only for learning purpose, not for any academic benefit or else. I`m already graduated and just trying to be more comfortable with java. I do respect education and learning though. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] allSwap(String[] strings) {

    // map of first characters, and the index where they were last seen
     Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap();

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {


         char firstChar = strings[i].charAt(0); 
         // box charAt(0)
        // remove firstChar from the map. If it's not found, returns null
         Integer removedIndex = map.remove(firstChar);

        if (removedIndex != null) {
             int j = removedIndex; 
            // unbox potentialIndex
            // swap values at thisIndex and thatIndex
             String temp = strings[j];
            strings[j] = strings[i];
            strings[i] = temp;
        } else {
            // save the index for possible swapping later
            map.put(firstChar, i); 
        }
    }

    return strings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work !

```
 public String[] allSwap(String[] strings) {
      
      
      Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
      
      
      for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++){
        
        if(!map.containsKey(strings[i].substring(0,1))){
          map.put(strings[i].substring(0,1),i);
        }
        else{
          String temp = strings[map.get(strings[i].substring(0,1))];
          strings[map.get(strings[i].substring(0,1))] = strings[i];
          strings[i] = temp;
          map.remove(strings[i].substring(0,1));
        }
        
      }
      
    return strings;
    }
```